# Android ActionBar is missing

Tags: java, android, xml

In My Project **MainActivity.java** is;--

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

In **res=>menu** I have **activity_main_actions.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Search / will display always -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <!-- Location Found -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_location_found"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_location_found"
          android:title="@string/action_location_found"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <!-- Refresh -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
          android:title="@string/action_refresh"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <!-- Help -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
          android:title="@string/action_help"
          android:showAsAction="never"/>

    <!-- Check updates -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_check_updates"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
          android:title="@string/action_check_updates"
          android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

my **Values => styles.xml** is:--

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

And my **Manifect.xml** is :--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.actionbar_example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And In my **layout folder I have activity_main.xml** i.e :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.actionbar_example.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I open this lauout in eclipse graphical view it is showing the actionBar with the items..But When I run this program in my android phone--action bar is missing..The output is white window with no ActionBar showing only "hello world"..Why I cant getting ActionBar window???Where is the problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend your Activity with `ActionBarActivity`

**Support Android 2.1 and Above**

Adding the action bar when running on versions older than Android 3.0 (down to Android 2.1) requires that you include the Android Support Library in your application.

To get started, read the [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) document and set up the **v7 appcompat** library (once you've downloaded the library package, follow the instructions for Adding libraries with resources).

Once you have the Support Library integrated with your app project:

Update your activity so that it extends `ActionBarActivity`. For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity { ... }
```

In your manifest file, update either the `<application>` element or individual `<activity>` elements to use one of the Theme.AppCompat themes. For example:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" ... >
```

Note: If you've created a custom theme, be sure it uses one of the Theme.AppCompat themes as its parent. For details, see Styling the Action Bar.
Now your activity includes the action bar when running on Android 2.1 (API level 7) or higher.

Remember to properly set your app's API level support in the manifest:

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"  android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

[source](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html)

Comment: I can get ActionBar in my activity if I do :--"public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity"..But I have to do "public class MainActivity extends Activity" for some reasons..So,what i have to do??

Comment: ActionBarActive does all What Activity do, I think it is inherited from Activity class. There might be reason to use ActionBar Activity but Activity does not matter.

Comment: @Ghost rider ActionBarActivity inherits from FragmentActivity and FragmentActivity from Activity

Answer (score 0):

change

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
```

and import required classes

Comment: I can get ActionBar in my activity if I do :--"public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity"..But I have to do "public class MainActivity extends Activity" for some reasons..So,what i have to do??

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
```

//     Change The Parent Theme

```
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```